# dplyr Time Diff between rows

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame in the below format and I'm trying to find the difference in time between the Event 'ASSIGNED' and the last time the Event is 'CREATED' that comes before it.

```
**AccountID**              **TIME**                    **EVENT**
1                      2016-11-08T01:54:15.000Z        CREATED
1                      2016-11-09T01:54:15.000Z        ASSIGNED
1                      2016-11-10T01:54:15.000Z        CREATED
1                      2016-11-11T01:54:15.000Z        CALLED
1                      2016-11-12T01:54:15.000Z        ASSIGNED
1                      2016-11-12T01:54:15.000Z        SLEEP
```

Currently my code is as follows, my difficulty is selecting the CREATED that just comes before the ASSIGNED Event

```
test <- timetable.filter %>%
  group_by(AccountID) %>%
  mutate(timeToAssign = ifelse(EVENT == 'ASSIGNED', 
                                interval(ymd_hms(TIME), max(ymd_hms(TIME[EVENT == 'CREATED']))) %/% hours(1), NA))
```

I'm looking for the output to be

```
**AccountID**              **TIME**                    **EVENT**        **timeToAssign**
1                      2016-11-08T01:54:15.000Z        CREATED         NA
1                      2016-11-09T01:54:15.000Z        ASSIGNED         12
1                      2016-11-10T01:54:15.000Z        CREATED         NA
1                      2016-11-11T01:54:15.000Z        CALLED         NA
1                      2016-11-12T01:54:15.000Z        ASSIGNED         24
1                      2016-11-12T01:54:15.000Z        SLEEP         NA
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: What is the unit in `timeToAssign`?

Comment: `timetable.filter %>%
  group_by(AccountID, cumsum(EVENT == "CREATED")) %>% mutate(timeToAssign  = ifelse(EVENT == 'ASSIGNED', TIME - first(TIME), NA))`. That should get you started.

Comment: Shouldn't the difference be 24 hours and 48 hours, respectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(anytime)

df %>% 
    group_by(AccountID) %>% 
    mutate(CREATED_INDEX = if_else(EVENT == 'CREATED', row_number(), NA_integer_),
           TIME = anytime(TIME)) %>% 
    fill(CREATED_INDEX) %>% 
    mutate(TimeToAssign = if_else(EVENT == 'ASSIGNED', 
                                  as.numeric(TIME - TIME[CREATED_INDEX], units = 'hours'), 
                                  NA_real_)) %>% 
    select(-CREATED_INDEX)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   AccountID [1]
#  AccountID                TIME    EVENT TimeToAssign
#      <int>              <dttm>   <fctr>        <dbl>
#1         1 2016-11-08 01:54:15  CREATED           NA
#2         1 2016-11-09 01:54:15 ASSIGNED           24
#3         1 2016-11-10 01:54:15  CREATED           NA
#4         1 2016-11-11 01:54:15   CALLED           NA
#5         1 2016-11-12 01:54:15 ASSIGNED           48
#6         1 2016-11-12 01:54:15    SLEEP           NA
```